# Holy Basil / Tulsi Plant Leaves Turning brown w/ netted holes

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, basil

My holy basil/tulsi plant was doing well up until a week ago when netted holes started appearing in brown spots on the leaves. I had not changed the location of the plant so the environment was relatively stable. Since then, I have also found tiny black bumps on the leaves. I was wondering what the problem may be. Thank you in advance for all the help!

Here are some images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the undersides of the leaves?

Comment: It could be Japanese beetles. To repel them do this: Japanese beetles can be plucked from the basil plant with your fingers and squished or dropped into soapy water to dispose. Source: https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/herbs/basil/holes-in-basil-leaves.htm

Comment: Japanese beetles feed on plant foliage. They're a metallic green color with copper wings and are approximately 1/2 inch long. They typically appear and begin feeding on plants during the early summer. Most of the damage they cause is aesthetic, and the plants are left with small holes throughout the leaves. Basil (Ocimum basilicum) is an annual that grows in U.S. Department of Agriculture plant hardiness zones 9 through 11, and it's particularly susceptible to Japanese beetle infestations. [Source](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/save-basil-plants-japanese-beetles-70980.html)